# How to access SQL server data from PostgreSQL (pgAdmin)?

Tags: postgresql

Need to access the SQL server data from pgAdmin. 
I have tried with foreign data wrapper, but it's not working.
I'm trying to access the data from " dbo.example " which is in SQL server from pgAdmin.
Please provide the prerequisites to achieve this.

### Sample Code:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;

CREATE SERVER mssql_pm_server
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
OPTIONS (host '121.112.141.88', port '1874');

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres
SERVER mssql_pm_server
OPTIONS ( user '1122', password '1122',dbname 'db_Product');    

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE mssql_pm_table1(
    BusinessEntityID int NOT NULL,
    TerritoryID text
)
SERVER mssql_pm_server 
OPTIONS (table_name  'dbo.example');
```

### Error:

> ERROR:  could not connect to server "mssql_pm_server"
>
> DETAIL:  server closed the connection unexpectedly    This probably
>   means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the
>   request.
>
> SQL state: 08001

Answer (score 2):

You need the proper foreign data wrapper to access Microsoft SQL server. The PostgreSQL foreign data wrapper is to connect to PostgreSQL databases.

You should use [tds_fdw](https://github.com/tds-fdw/tds_fdw).

Comment: could you please elaborate on this..bcz i'm new to this and not able access the link too.

Comment: Every type of data source needs a specific foreign data wrapper. To access the link, you must get an internet connection.

Comment: please tell me how add this extension

ERROR:  could not open extension control file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/share/extension/tds_fdw.control": No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01

Comment: You did not install the foreign data wrapper. You have to compile and install it.

Comment: i have downloaded the tds_fdw file,but i dont know how to install this..could you please help me to do

Comment: You need a compiler and follow the instructions. I cannot help you there since I never built tds_fdw myself.